# Merging switches

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

Ok I have one light switch that works a shop light I have another switch that works a fan I want to take both out put new shop light in but I want to operate new light with either switch CAN SOMEONE PLEASE HELP

Comment: Are the switches in the same box, a 2-gang box?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: NO I CANNOT HELP.. Also, at least try with some punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

getting two switches to operate the same lamp requires that the switches be interconnected with three wires , it may also require that the switches be upgraded
to as different type.